# How to find replace using regex groups in vim

Tags: regex, vim

I'm replacing all the inline gist snippets w/ a div to load them in a non blocking way. To modify all the legacy articles that have the following

```
<script src='https://gist.github.com/1234.js?file=gistfile1.sh'></script>
```

I need to replace it with the following instead

```
<div data-gist=1234><a href='http://gist.github.com/1234'>gistfile1.m</a></div>
```

So far what I'm trying (vim newb here) -doesn't seem to work

```
:%s/<script src='https:\/\/gist.github.com\/(d+).js?file=gistfile1.sh'><\/script>/<div data-gist={1}><a href='http://gist.github.com/{1}'>gistfile1.m</a></div>//g
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I got it to work with this:

```
:%s!<script src='https://gist.github.com/\(\d\+\).js?file=gistfile1.sh'></script>!<div data-gist=\1><a href='http://gist.github.com/\1'>gistfile1.m</a></div>!g
```

Couple things to note:

1. I used `!` instead of `/` as seperator to avoid having to escape path slashes
2. You need to escape `(`, `d`, `+`, and `)` in your attempt.
3. You had extra `/` at the very end.
4. To insert the match group, use `\1` instead of `{1}`

Comment: nice! the only thing to note is you need to start that with :%s

Comment: one quick edit -how can I ignore the file= (name of file varies) and I don't need this during the replace so it could be lost (sorry to scope creep) **turns out I had various file names for each gist and they don't actually mean much for this implementation

Comment: If you don't care for the file name, you can just do `file=[^']\+'`. That will match everything after `file=` until the next `'`. If you want to use the name in the second part, then wrap another capture group around it `()`.

Comment: You are the man! thanks for the speedy and documented answer!

Comment: someone give bounty... :)

Comment: @Tim why does vim require you to escape the `(` and `)` when trying to make a capture group but other special characters `*[^$`, etc. don't require this? It's confusing as someone coming from python regex where bracketing directly results in capturing (e.g. in python to get the first and last character of a line you would want `^(.).*(.)$` but in Vim you have to do `^\(.\).*\(.\)$`. I guess my confusion is that usually when you escape a character, it implies you want to use its literal value; in this case we are doing the opposite, which feels inconsistent so I'm confused.